Adding Nitro Rollup config options breaks build process in Nuxt app
I'm using Nuxt and I needed to compile a couple specific .ts files into modules to be run. I've added the following into the nuxt.config.ts file:
nitro: {
    rollupConfig: {
      input: ['./server/app.ts', './server/process1.ts', './server/process2.ts'],
      output: {
        inlineDynamicImports: false,
        dir: "lib",
        format: "module",
        entryFileNames: "[name].js"
      }
    }
  }

This runs as expected and adds 3 new .js files into a folder called "lib". The problem is that adding this code seems to have reverted/stopped/interfered with the regular build process for the rest of my nitro server (presumably nuxt's own build config).
The regular behavior would be that the nitro output files are generated to the .output directory but this directory doesnt have the regular files that it had before adding this to my nuxt.config.ts file.
Is there a way I can add it so that this doesn't affect the regular build process?

The simplest way I found to achieve this, is using the nitro:build:before hook.
import path from 'node:path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...
  hooks: {
    'nitro:build:before': nitro => {
      if (nitro.options.rollupConfig) {
        nitro.options.rollupConfig.input = {
           // This is nitros default entry, which will generate the ./output/server/index.mjs
          index: nitro.options.entry, 
          // These are the Custom entrypoints, where the key will
          // be the name of the script in the output directory.
          // NOTE: the `../` at the beginning of the path is required
          //       because `import.meta.url` resolves to the nuxt.config.ts
          //       itself and not the the root of the project.
          app: fileURLToPath(path.join(import.meta.url, '../server/app.ts')), 
          process1: fileURLToPath(path.join(import.meta.url, '../server/process1.ts')),
          process2: fileURLToPath(path.join(import.meta.url, '../server/process2.ts')),

          // or when your script is in the server dir you could also use:
          process2: fileURLToPath(path.join(nitro.options.srcDir, './process2.ts')),
        };

        nitro.options.rollupConfig.output = {
          entryFileNames: '[name].mjs',
        };
      }
    },
  },
  ...
});

This will produce the following output structure:
.output/
  public/
  server/
    chunks/
    node_modules/
    app.mjs
    index.mjs
    package.json
    process1.mjs
    process2.mjs

And using node .output/server/index.mjs starts the Server as it would without the modifications.
